# how to add scaffolds in virtual environment. I want to add Akhet scaffold into my virtual environment?

Tags: pyramid, pylons, akhet

after all googling and searching i came here...
I want to use Akhet http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Akhet scaffold and i want to continue with that to develop my application. 
Now the problem is that i don't have any idea to include any scaffold in my virtual environment.
I have tried with the following lines 
`env/bin/pcreate -s akhet pythonakhen`
Since i don't have akhet in my scaffold list the line given me an error 
`Unavailable scaffolds: ['akhet']`.
please help me to add any scaffalod in my virtual environment so that i can us them to generate the skeleton of the application.

Answer (score 2):

Forget Akhet. The current version 2.0 does not provide a scaffold anymore and is rather outdated. Just follow the official pyramid documentation, there is plenty of stuff builtin if you rely on the scaffolds shipped with pyramid 1.5 and the way it works in year 2014.

- [Akhet scaffold is gone](https://akhet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rant_scaffold.html)
- [if you want to provide Akhet scaffolding in future :-)](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/scaffolding.html)

These links are your friends

- http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/index.html#getting-started